# Firebird database not being restored when running in VirtualBox

Tags: c#, virtualbox, firebird2.5

I have a Windows 7 application, running in VirtualBox VM.  It used to restore the database when running natively using System.Diagnostics.Process, but stopped a few months ago. This is my code:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
bookConn.Close();  //  close the connection

FbRestore restoreSvc = new FbRestore();
restoreSvc.ConnectionString = "User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;DataSource=localhost;Database=" + dbPath + ";Pooling=true;";
restoreSvc.BackupFiles.Add(new FbBackupFile(backupFilename, 2048));
restoreSvc.PageSize = 4096;
restoreSvc.Options = FbRestoreFlags.Create | FbRestoreFlags.Replace;
restoreSvc.ServiceOutput += new ServiceOutputEventHandler(ServiceOutput);
restoreSvc.Execute();

Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
```

I can restore from the command line, but not from within the Windows application.   Any ideas why not?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the hostname (or IP address!) (`DataSource`) in the connection string?

Comment: There is no place for *DataSource*... everything is in the *ConnectionString* and the path is correct; also, there is no exception thrown.

Comment: What do you mean with 'no place for `DataSource`'? It is a name-value property that you can define **inside** the connection string, see http://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird/ I don't know if it will fix the issue (otherwise I would have posted an answer), it is a troubleshooting step.

Comment: NO, that didn't help... any other ideas on how to restore a .gbk file programmatically?

Comment: What is in ServiceOutput's event message(s)? Firebird will show you very likely error there.

Comment: Cincura.net: I tried it and nothing!  Still is not restoring, and there is NO output in the ServiceOutput event messages!  Is that significant?

Comment: Cincura.net:  I tried restoring from the command line, and that works; it just won't restore from within the app.  I have updated the code in the original question.

Comment: Are you running your application as an Admin? Could it be a permissions issue? If you debug and step through do all steps complete successfully or return any status codes / messages? For example, rather than just `restoreSvc.Execute();` why don't you try `var result = restoreSvc.Execute();` and see what `result` contains. Finally, have you tried setting **Verbose=true** as I have heard that might resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment here are a few things to try:

First, to try and get some logging going and I recall reading somewhere about a "known" bug where you sometimes need to force `verbose=true` please try with this code snippet:

```
public void RestoreDatabase(string dbPath)
{
    FbRestore restoreSvc = new FbRestore();

    restoreSvc.ConnectionString = "User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;DataSource=localhost;Database=" + dbPath + ";Pooling=true;";
    restoreSvc.BackupFiles.Add(new FbBackupFile(BackupRestoreFile, 2048));
    restoreSvc.Verbose = true; // Enable verbose logging
    restoreSvc.PageSize = 4096;
    restoreSvc.Options = FbRestoreFlags.Create | FbRestoreFlags.Replace;

    restoreSvc.ServiceOutput += new ServiceOutputEventHandler(ServiceOutput);

    restoreSvc.Execute();
}

private void ServiceOutput(object sender, ServiceOutputEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

This should then hopefully shed some light on what is happening as you should start to get some logging. `Execute` **MAY** terminate immediately though so you need to ensure that your app doesn't end while the backup is still restoring and writing to the `ServiceOutput` etc.

It would also be worth checking that when you run your application you are running as an administrator to ensure there are no strange Windows permission issues.

Comment: This is the result of Verbose = true;    gbak:opened file D:\Email Attachments\B2014-maria.gbk 
A first chance exception of type 'FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException' occurred in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll
A first chance exception of type 'FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException' occurred in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll

Comment: It is from an email attachment? Have you checked that you have "Unblocked" the file? Was that the whole exception, any stack trace?

Comment: Also, can you check that non new machines have been added to your network recently? If so can you check that your machine's name is unique?

Comment: No, this is not from an email attachment (I copied the message from the console output); no exception, no stack trace... it just doesn't work. The machine's name is unique: **ROLF-PC**.  There are no other computers on this network.